# Exporting to Unity - How do you get a single FBX to support multiple materials?

Tags: materials, unity

I was looking at some FBX's in Unity and noticed they support multiple materials, like this:

[image]

When modeling in Blender (I'm using Blender Render), how would I go about setting up a model to have multiple materials like that? My workflow currently is:

- Select all the faces of the object
- UV Unwrap
- Open up a PNG in the UV/Image Editor window
- Position the UVs
- Export

This produces a FBX in Unity which handles only 1 material. What do I need to do differently in Blender to have a model support and offer up multiple material slots?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each material you assign in Blender, will be a material in Unity.

It looks you already have that, if Unity has generated all those material slots. You will just need to re-assign the colour in Unity, or attach the texture you've used if I read your question correctly.

[image]

Each face has a different material on it, 3 materials in Blender, Unity will read that and create three materials for those faces.

Comment: Thanks! I'd never really dabbled in the material panel. 

For anyone else wondering how this done I also found this video which is a good step by step: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3r5VvN89O1Q